# Array expecting string error when fieldtype is used within matrix

Tags: plugin-development

Im getting an expecting string given array error on a variable in my fieldtype. When output / dumped to the template it is a string. This only happens when used within matrix field.

The trim function here is the specific line throwing the error:

```
$settings['colours'] = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', trim($settings['colours'])));
```

getInputHtml() & prepValue()

```
public function prepValue($value)
{
    $colour = new FruitStyle_PaletteModel();

    if(is_array($value))
    {
        $colour->hex = $value['hex'];
        $colour->opacity = $value['opacity'];
    }

    return $colour;
}

public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
{
    craft()->templates->includeJsResource('fruitstyle/js/FruitPalette.js');
    craft()->templates->includeCssResource('fruitstyle/css/palette.css');
    craft()->templates->includeCssResource('fruitstyle/fonts/fruiticons/style.css');

    $id = craft()->templates->formatInputId($name);
    craft()->templates->includeJs('new FruitPalette("'.craft()->templates->namespaceInputId($id).'");');

    // String or JSON
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    if(filter_var($settings['colours'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $settings['colours']);
        $colours = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $settings['colours'] = JsonHelper::decode($colours, true);
    }
    else
    {
        $settings['colours'] = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', trim($settings['colours'])));
    }

    return craft()->templates->render('fruitstyle/_fieldtype/palette/input', array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'value' => $value,
        'settings' => $settings,
        'specialOptions' => $this->_getSpecialOptions(),
    ));
}
```

[image: PHP Error]

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though `$settings['colours']` is an array... which you're then trying to trim and explode.

Can you `var_dump($settings['colours'])`?

p.s. Nice to see "colours" spelt "correctly" :)

Comment: Is this a plugin that you've developed? Is it maybe saving the colours as a list of colours or RGB values?

Comment: I voted you up in spite of your gleeful misspelling of the word "colors". :)

Comment: Gents, this is the confusing bit that I was trying to explain (badly) when var_dump or dump() in the template its says that it's a string!! Baffled.

Comment: @BradBell he spelled it perfectly fine.

Comment: So if you insert a line before line 86 of `FruitStyle_PaletteFieldType.php` and add `var_dump($settings["colours"]);` ... does it report a string?